# How to add numpy array variables by index without using loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have this problem where I would prefer not using loops because I am working with a big data as a solution :

This is what I am trying to do : *(I know this works to [6 6 6], but I want to "join" it by index)*

```
import numpy as np

np_1 = np.asarray([1,1,1])
np_2 = np.asarray([2,2,2])
np_3 = np.asarray([3,3,3])

np_4 = np_1 + np_2 + np_3
# np_4 should be [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Are there ways to do this? or should I look for options outside of numpy?

Comment: what you're trying to do is array *stacking* - see the numpy docs guide [how to create an array from existing data](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html?highlight=stack#how-to-create-an-array-from-existing-data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly stack numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644397/how-to-properly-stack-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.array([np_1, np_2, np_3]).transpose().flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method:

```
np.ravel(np.stack(np_1,np_2,np3),'F')
```

Comment: I think you are missing a set of brackets. This is a TypeError as currently posted. Also the typo: `np3` -> `np_3`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to stack the sequences depth-wise and flatten it:

```
np.dstack([np_1, np_2, np_3]).flatten()
```